# How to stop a resizable <div> inside a flexbox from jumping when resized

Tags: html, css

I have two `<div>`'s inside a flexbox, and I'm trying to make the first `<div>` resizable, while the second `<div>` should fill the remaining space in the `<div>`.

I have functioning code, but the resizable `<div>` jumps a bit when you try to resize it (firefox & edge), and I'm not sure why, or how to stop it from doing that ;-;

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cftou6rL/

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

#div1 {
  background: red;
}

#div2 {
  background: lightblue;
  height: max-content;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.resizable {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container resizable">

  <div id="div1" class="resizable">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>

  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the jumping/snapping issue by using a `<grid>` instead of `<flex>` (and a bit of duct tape) :/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div class="container">

  <div id="div1" class="resizable">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  
  <div id="div2">
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1000fr; /* Without this div2 doesn't stick to div1 when div1 is small */
  
  background: yellow;
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
}

#div1 {
  background: red;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  min-height: 50px; /* Consequence of the 1000fr thing */
  max-height: 200px; /* Otherwise resize can escape from the grid */
}

#div2 {
  background: lightblue;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}


.resizable {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when the container doesn't have enough space to push div2 down.
So I put the height of the container fixed (not resizable).
but the 2 divs inside it are perfectly resizable as long as their total height doesn't exceed the height of the parent.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <body>
   <div class="container">
      
      <div id="div1" class="resizable">
      <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1> 
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
      
      <div id="div2" class="resizable">
      <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1> 
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <h1>hello</h1>
      </div>
     
     </div>
</body>
<style>

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: yellow;
      height: 500px;
      width: 150px;
    }
    
    #div1 {
      background: red;
      max-height: 250px;
      overflow: auto;
      }
    
    #div2 {
      background: lightblue;
      max-height: 250px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
    
    .resizable {
      resize: vertical;
      overflow: auto;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there any way to fix this (or an alternate implementation) when the total height *does* exceed the height of the parents? The use case is div2 holds a list of items (that definitely overflows the page) and div1 holds some options to sort that list of items, which doesn't need to be visible at all times

Comment: @Highfire1 I edited the code. I added the overflows for divs individually.
So I think as long as they have overflow: auto , I don't think they need too much space. But they can't exceed the background height. They don't need to exceed anyways because they have overflow on them. right?

Comment: sorry I think there was a misunderstanding: I also want div2 to fill the remaining space in the page (or in this case parent div)

Comment: i was able to get rid of the snapping by using grid instead of flexbox but now there are other issues ._.

Comment: Yes !  it looks very neat and clean now ! You just need some font styling for it. I kinda liked the yellow background it had before . It felt very fun  But I would prefer your latest one for a professional website.